# Author indentation ISSUE While Writing IEEE paper

Tags: ieeetran, author

There is an indentation problem in author section of the IEEE paper.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{PAPER TITLE\\
%{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and should not be used}
}
%\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}


\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author1}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Engineering Department} \\
\textit{XYZ Univeristy of Engineering and Technology }\\
Karachi, Pakistan \\
 author1@gmail.com}
\and
\\
\IEEEauthorblockN{author2}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{ Engineering Department} \\
\textit{XYZ Univeristy of Engineering and Technology}\\
Karachi, Pakistan \\
  author2@gmail.com}
\and
\\
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author3}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Engineering Department} \\
\textit{XYZ Univeristy of Engineering and Technology}\\
Karachi, Pakistan \\
  author3@gmail.com}
\and
\\
\IEEEauthorblockN{ author4 }
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Engineering Department} \\
\textit{XYZ Univeristy of Engineering and Technology}\\
Karachi, Pakistan \\
author4@gmail.com}
\and
\\
\IEEEauthorblockN{ author5}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Engineering Department} \\
\textit{XYZ Univeristy of Engineering and Technology}\\
Karachi, Pakistan \\
author5@gmail.com }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IEEEtrans manual recommend to use the long format if you have more than three authors.

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, James K irk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, Montgomer Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}} 
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Ele ctrical and Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta, Georgia 30 332 --0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu} \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Cen tury Fox, Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}}
```

[image]